# Scene2d LibGDX Java - Does addActor(myactor) work inside other classes?

Tags: java, android, oop, libgdx, scene2d

If I declare a Stage 'myStage' inside the main class of my game, and then pass this to the constructor of my Player (which extends Actor). Can I then use that copy of myStage to add other actors to the main stage (ie. Adding array of bullets inside the Player class, or even such things as Buttons from the Button class) from coding within the Player class.

Or does this cause issues? Whereby I have to addActor() code from only the class where the stage was declared in the first instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this (give or take):

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    ...
    Stage myStage = new Stage();
    Player myPlayer = new Player(myStage);

    myStage.addActor(myPlayer);
    ...
}

...

public class Player extends Actor
{

    Stage myStage;        

    public Player(Stage _stage)
    {
        myStage = _stage;

        myStage.addActor(<another Actor object>);
    }
}
```

Since all objects in Java are references, when you pass myStage to myPlayer, you are not copying myStage, instead you're passing a reference to the Stage you already declared and initialized.

In short, you can call myStage.addActor() from inside your Player class without a problem. I would recommend taking a look at your class structure, however, to make sure that objects (such as your player) only encapsulate their own functionality. For example, if the buttons are only for control, maybe they should be added to the stage separately from the main method as a UI class that extends Actor.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Youve cleared up my misunderstanding there first try :) when i get home will put the code into action